# SAS logical expression; how to use AND NOT

Tags: sas

I have seen a SAS data like this.

```
data combined;
merge demo(in=d) history(in=p); by id;
if d and not p;
run;
```

What does `if d and not p` mean?  My textbook says it is the same as

```
a. if d>p or
b. if d^=p and d
c. if d^=p and not p
d. All of above.
```

My guess was b, but I am not sure what the correct understanding of the logic is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is using the dataset option IN

When merging:
If a record is found in DEMO, D is set to 1, otherwise 0. 
If a record is found in HISTORY, P is set to 1, otherwise 0.

For evaluating SAS logic, 1 can be considered TRUE and 0 is false.

Answers to evaluate to true:
If d>p -> only true when D=1, P=0

If d ne p and d -> D=1, P=0
For an AND to be TRUE both components must be true which means D =1.

If d ne p and NOT P -> D=1, P=0
NOT P to be TRUE means P=0

All resolve to the same so the answer is D.